# Как в сообщение через alert можно сделать пробелы между слов? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Да, возможно тупой вопрос, но я новичок

```
var myName = prompt('Как вас зовут?');
    var mySurname = prompt('Какая у вас фамилия?');
    var myBirthYear = prompt('Какой у вас год рождения?');

    var currentYear = 2019;
    var age = currentYear - myBirthYear;

    if (age < 20) {
      alert('Привет,' + myName + mySurname + '!');
     }
      else if (age >= 20 && age < 40) {
        alert('Добрый день,' + myName + mySurname);
      }
      else {
        alert('Здравствуйте,' + myName + mySurname);
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В самом Стринге-аргументе поставить пробел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> alert('Привет,' + myName + mySurname + '!');
> ```

```
alert('Привет, ' + myName + ' ' + mySurname + '!');
```

Answer (score 4):

[Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) (ES6+):

```
/* ... */
const fullName = `${myName} ${mySurname}`; 
if (age < 20)
  alert(`Привет, ${fullName}!`);
else if (age >= 20 && age < 40)
  alert(`Добрый день, ${fullName}`);
else
  alert(`Здравствуйте, ${fullName}`);
```